# how to get all the values inside JSON with a common name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I need to get an array of all the `name` values from a JSON structure.

My JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "profile": {
    "G5j7": {
      "name": "siddharth",
      "age": "17"
    },
    "Loj9": {
      "name": "ram",
      "age": "20"
    },
    "Huy8": {
      "name": "maix"
    }
  }
}
```

I can get a specific `name` value by:

```
var singleName = profile.G5j7.name;
```

But how do I get an array of all the `name` values if don't know all the IDs inside `profile`? I need to store in a variable.

Comment: It is the customer ID inside my API ,So I want **Each ID's name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`. This function getting field names from in object to array.

```js
let data = { "profile": { "G5j7": { "name": "siddharth", "age": "17" }, "Loj9": { "name": "ram", "age": "20" }, "Huy8": { "name": "maix" } } } 
let propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data.profile)
propNames.forEach((propname) => { console.log(data.profile[propname].name) })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const arrayName = Object.values(profile).map((item) => item.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.values(yourObj.profile).map(v => v.name)
```

Object.values() returns an array of the values on every (own) prop of your object. So you can forget about the property names and iterate on its values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all properties keys in an Object, with that you can get access to all profile object keys with that you can retrieve name for each key like bellow

```js
let data = {
    "profile": {
        "G5j7": {
            "name": "siddharth",
            "age": "17"
        },
        "Loj9": {
            "name": "ram",
            "age": "20"
        },
        "Huy8": {
            "name": "maix"
        }
  }
};

let profiles_keys = Object.keys(data.profile);

let results = profiles_keys.reduce((accumulator, current)=> {
    return accumulator.concat(data.profile[current].name)
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
const names = Object.values(profile).map((profile) => profile.name);
```

`Object.values()` returns an array of the values.
Then for each profile, use `.map()` to get each `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "profile":
    { "G5j7": { "name": "siddharth", "age": "17" },
      "Loj9": { "name": "ram", "age": "20" },
      "Huy8": { "name": "maix" }
    }
};



for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.profile)) {
  console.log(`${value.name}`);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    const decodedJsonObject = "  {         "profile": {     "G5j7": {       "name": "siddharth",       "age": "17"     },     "Loj9": {       "name": "ram",       "age": "20"     },     "Huy8": {       "name": "maix"     }        } }"
 var singleName = profile.G5j7.name;
```

Comment: No I want all the name in an array without specifying ID